# How to make excel column allow to take upto 24 decimal places and show number only upto the decimal places entered(don't want to show trailing zeroes)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Have an excel with a score column where values can be entered between 1 to 100 with decimal places upto 24 digits. When giving format as number and decimal places upto 24, trailing zeroes are coming for values ex 2 is showing as 2.000000000000000000000000

How to show the value till relevant decimal place like 2, 3.45,4.789 and hide trailing zeroes?
Also need solution without use of macros

Can we do something with conditional formatting or is any other solution is there?

Comment: You can't get more than 15 digits of precision out of Excel (without using a decimal type in VBA) so I'm not sure your question can be answered. However, you could try =LEFT(A1,LEN(A1))

Comment: Store the number as text.